# Is it possible to use .exceptionCount(true) twice?

Tags: crossfilter, reductio

i have a problem, I want to count the different elements of bar and num associated with foo

```
var data = crossfilter([
{ foo: 'one', bar: 'A', num: '1' },
{ foo: 'two', bar: 'B', num: '2' },
{ foo: 'three', bar: 'A', num: '3' },
{ foo: 'one', bar: 'B', num: '3' },
{ foo: 'one', bar: 'A', num: '2' },
{ foo: 'two', bar: 'B', num: '2' },
]);
```

ie, I want to get, for example:

```
[ { key: 'one', value: { exceptionCount: 2, exceptionCount2: 3 },    // 'bar' dimension has 2 values: 'A' and 'B', and has 3 values: '1' and '2' and '3'
{ key: 'two', value: { exceptionCount: 1, exceptionCount2: 1 },    // 'bar' dimension has 1 value: 'B', '2'
{ key: 'three', value: { exceptionCount: 1 , exceptionCount2: 1} ] // 'bar' dimension has 1 value: 'A', '3'
```

I have use of the reductio library with exceptionCount to separate for num and bar, but I could not join both associated with only foo.

Can you help me, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `reductio.value` method lets you put multiple reducers of the same type on a group. There is an example in the README using `exceptionSum` that can be adapted to use `exceptionCount`. Your group structure will change a bit.

https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-reductio-b-value-b-i-propertyname-i-

Comment: Thank you, i put the answer below, but i have a new problem with dc.js and geoChoroplethChart.

Comment: You should open a new question for the second issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

I use

```
 reducer=reductio();
 reducer.value('nbar').exception(function(d){return d['bar']}.exceptionCount(true);
 reducer.value('nnum').exception(function(d){return d['num']}.exceptionCount(true);
```

and i apply to group.

```
 reducer(my_group_name);
```